# iOS UITableView header loaded from XIB

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I have a problem while trying to load `UITableView` header from `XIB`

Inside my `viewDidLoad()` method I have implemented:

```
let tableHeaderView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed(
    "MyCustomHeader",
    owner: nil,
    options: nil
).first as! MyCustomHeader

tableHeaderView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

tableView.tableHeaderView = tableHeaderView
```

Debugger shows, that the `tableHeaderView` is initialised with the correct frame.

Although, inside the `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`, `tableHeaderView` height is sat up to `0.0`.

How can I avoid this automatic resizing?

Comment: Implement `UITableViewDelegate` method - `heightForHeaderInSection`

Comment: try answer below, if it solve your problem@Daumantas Versockas

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't. This method is related with a section header frame, meanwhile I need a table header.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
let view = (NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("MenuHeader", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? UIView)
tableView.tableHeaderView = view
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38450753/3901620

Comment: What difference does it make while speaking about header automatic resizing?

Answer (score 0):

Header height can be applied again. Try this,

```
let tableHeaderView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed(
        "MyCustomHeader",
        owner: nil,
        options: nil
    ).first as! MyCustomHeader

    tableHeaderView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tableHeaderView.setNeedsLayout()
    tableHeaderView.layoutIfNeeded()
    let height = tableHeaderView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
    var frame = tableHeaderView.frame
    tableHeaderView.size.height = height
    tableHeaderView.frame = frame
    tableView.tableHeaderView = tableHeaderView
```